# ValueError at /api/addorderitem badly formed hexadecimal UUID string in Django rest framework

Tags: django, string, django-rest-framework, hex, uuid

I tried to create a random unique string in a charfield using uuid but it is giving me above error.

My model is:

from utils import create_new_ref_number

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    #user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True
   orderItem_ID = models.UUIDField(max_length=12, editable=False,default=str(uuid.uuid4()))
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order,on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True,null=True,related_name='order_items')
    item = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, null=True)
    order_variants = models.ForeignKey(Variants,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)    
    total_item_price = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True,null=True,)
```

Comment: Why are you turning your uuid into a string? Also you don't need to call the `uuid` function. `default=uuid.uuid4`

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide the error details too